# WEB API returning TSV instead of XML/Json

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How can i make MVC or WEBAPI return TSV instead of XML or Json?
Is there any converter that will make this possible for me?

I have this API which returns either XML or Json, but i now want it to return tsv:
http://api.friliv.dk/api/miintoproducts

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I have been trying to add TSV as a tag to this question, but the system keeps reverting to CSV, which is not what i mean

Comment: mosi98, i dont see anyting about TSV in that blog post